# Is there a way to remove the requirement for Safari to be installed on email invitees devices

Tags: ios, crashlytics

we only have Edge installed on some corporate ios devices, when receiving an email invite, the link tries to open/access Safari resulting in an error "Safari is required" can we configure this to allow Edge to be used, as security software restricts the ability to copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you can use what is called a `URLScheme` to open content inside of another app if that app has a `URLScheme` defined. This allows apps to do things like open the Twitter app right to someones Twitter profile etc.

While it is kind of a goofy solution, you are in luck because Microsoft has defined a `URLScheme` for Edge. If you prepend `microsoft-edge-http://` or `microsoft-edge-https://` to your url, iOS will ask Edge to open the link instead of Safari.

You will have to test what happens if someone clicks on this link when they don't have edge installed and if it doesn't work, then you could have your email include a link that will open directly in Edge and one that will open in Safari.

Comment: Thanks that’s helpful and can test this, however I do not have control over the email content as this is sent by crashlytics, but hoping the may have an answer here too

Comment: Ok, this is even goofier but you could make an app that allows URLs to open it via a share sheet and make it so that whenever someone opens that app, it immediately open's Edge. The workflow would look like this: In Email > Hold down on link > open with... > pick our goofy app > system opens goofy app > goofy app immediately opens Edge with the original link. Not sure how desperate you are but if nobody comes along with a better solution, I'm pretty certain this will work.